# save and continue form using php and mysql

Tags: php, mysqli

anyone here knows how to make a save and continue? I have a multi page form and it have many different parts so I need a save and continue form so they can fill out this form on the other day.

So firstly a user will log in into his/her account and they will see this link,

[see image here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/2Rebw.png)

Once they will click on it, they will see a multi page form like this,

[form image](https://i.stack.imgur.com/ygdX0.png)

When the user has filled out these data,

Sample data,

[sample data 1](https://i.stack.imgur.com/w11KP.png)

[sample data 2](https://i.stack.imgur.com/q1SF3.png)

So when the user click save, the data that the user have input will be save so when they will log in back into his/her account the data that has been saved will be displayed in the form.

Saved data,

[saved data 1](https://i.stack.imgur.com/AFUMt.png)

[saved data 2](https://i.stack.imgur.com/fClPC.png)

I have not yet tried any code because I'm new to php and mysql so please help! Thank you so much.

Comment: Stack overflow isn't here to write your code for you or teach you how to use php and mysql from scratch; you need to actually read some guides/docs, write some code and then come back with _specific_ problems you've encountered.

Answer (score 1):

Each time a user selects Next, add the data provided by the user to the relevant row in a database table. In this row, have a status column with status 'Draft' until the user completes the form upon which you change the status to 'Completed'. 
Each time a user opens the form, load any data already entered in the past by this user.
You might consider using a column to store information about the latest page of the form used by the user, so the user can resume at that particular page of the form later.
We are not here to provide you with all the code. If you have a problem or question related to a part of the code, feel free to ask though. 
Good luck!

Answer (score 0):

When the user clicks on the Next Button, Save the Data into your Mysql DB in a Save Block.
In the Save block user "INSERT" Query to Insert Data to DB.
After that use PHP "header" function to redirect to the same page.